# Is there a way to STOP selecting after reaching a certain element (using sibling selector)

Tags: css, css-selectors, siblings

I am using a sibling selector to select all divs after a certain element. Can I stop selecting after reaching a certain div?

Comment: Probably, yes. How are you identifying that "certain div"?

Comment: Before we go any further, can I clarify that the selector: `.sidebarRegion-1VBisG nav > div > div:nth-child(16)` will work just as well as the selector you've given immediately above?

Comment: In that case, you could deploy something like this: `.sidebarRegion-1VBisG nav > div > div:nth-child(4) ~ div {color: rgb(255, 0, 0);}`, followed by this: `.sidebarRegion-1VBisG nav > div > div:nth-child(17) {color: rgb(0, 0, 0);}`. The first selector selects all divs _after_ a certain element (ie. the 4th div). The second selector stops that selection after reaching a certain element (ie. the 16th div).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CSS :not

In this simple snippet the div after which things are not to be selected is identified by a class, but you can use any means you have of identifying it (e.g. nth-child).

```css
.parent>div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: red;
}

.parent>div:not(.dontselectanythingafterme ~ div) {
  background: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="dontselectanythingafterme">dont select anything after me</div>

  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>

</div>
```